# Column count doesn't match with the value count in row 1

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I am trying to populate a mqsql table with random values. I created a stored procedure for this but it gives me the error "column count doesn't match with the value count in row 1" when I execute it.

Below is what I have tried

The stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GenerateManagerData`()
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
WHILE i <= 100 DO
INSERT INTO projectManager(id,name,email,contact_number) VALUES (i+ 'M', CAST(i AS CHAR(10)), 'e'+ CAST(i AS CHAR(10))+ '@gmail.com', 'TP' + CAST(i AS CHAR(10)));
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
END
```

This is the table I have created

```
CREATE TABLE `projectmanager` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_number` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`)
);
```

I have given all the columns in the stored procedure. Please help me with this.

Comment: `VALUES (i, 'M', CAST(i AS CHAR(10)), 'e', CAST(i AS CHAR(10)), '@gmail.com', 'TP' , CAST(i AS CHAR(10)))` <-- you are trying to insert 8 fields against the 4 availables in your table. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: edited to add 04 fields with + marks. The same error comes

Comment: use [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), not `+`

Comment: Unrelated to the error: `+` is not the string concatenating operator in MySQL. Use the `concat()` function to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with the CAST funation. Using CONCAT() fixed the issue,

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GenerateManagerData`()
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 38;
WHILE i <= 100 DO
INSERT INTO projectManager(name,email,contact_number) VALUES (CONCAT('M', i), CONCAT('e', i, '@gmail.com'), CONCAT('TP', i));
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
END
```